# pylatexenc fails dividing paragraphs

Tags: python, parsing, latex

I am parsing a Latex document using `pylatexenc`. I don't have experience with this package, found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570467/156201).

I have this simple Latex document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{This is my Latex document}
\author{Gordon Shumway}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

First paragraph.

This is a second paragraph in the first section.

\section{Second section}

Many times we have equations like this one 
\begin{equation}
\left(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m\right)\left|\psi\right\rangle =0\label{Equation: Dirac}
\end{equation}
 and inline math such as $\psi$. And I can insert a reference to~(\ref{Equation: Dirac}).
\end{document}
```

As can be seen there are two paragraphs in the first section. If I parse the document using `pylatexenc` with the following code

```
from pylatexenc.latexwalker import LatexWalker

with open('latex_document.tex', 'r') as file:
    latex_file_str = file.read()

w = LatexWalker(latex_file_str)
nodelist,_,_ = w.get_latex_nodes(pos=0)

document = None
for node in nodelist:
    if hasattr(node, 'environmentname'):
        if node.environmentname == 'document':
            document = node

for node in document.nodelist:
    print(node, end=4*'\n')
    
document_title = None
for node in document.nodelist:
    if hasattr(node, 'macroname'):
        if node.macroname=='title':
            document_title = node
print(f'Title = {document_title.nodeargd.argnlist[0].nodelist[0].chars}')
```

however, the two paragraphs are parsed into a single element:

```
Bla bla bla...
LatexCharsNode(parsing_state=<parsing state 140254491546672>, pos=134, len=70, chars='\n\nFirst paragraph.\n\nThis is a second paragraph in the first section.\n\n')
Bla bla bla...
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this to be expected? Is this a limitation of `pylatexenc`?

Answer (score 1):

As you note, `pylatexenc` currently doesn't split paragraphs.  An idea would have been to declare the characters `\n\n` as "latex specials" (see, e.g. [here](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latex2text/#custom-latex-conversion-rules-a-simple-template)), but internally `pylatexenc` treats whitespace specially and this idea doesn't work.  You could post a feature request on [github](https://github.com/phfaist/pylatexenc/issues) or submit a pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

Your string with multiple paragraphs can be parsed with `splitlines():`

```
paragraphs = chars.splitlines()
```

Where `paragraphs` is a list of strings split by line breaks.